# React-native fetch (ios) RANDOMLY failing https requests with Network Request Failed

Tags: ios, react-native, fetch, lets-encrypt

I am getting randomly failing fetch post `https` requests. This is happening randomly i.e. 1 out of 15-20 times. The error only states

> Network Request Failed

and nothing else. I use a certificate from `lets-encrypt` so i assume it fulfills the requirements. What could be the reason?

```
const apiRequest = (payload, endpoint, secure ,next) => {
const address = secure ? secureServerAddress + endpoint : serverAddress + endpoint
//const address = serverAddress + endpoint
console.log('[PAYLOAD]', JSON.stringify(payload))
console.log('[ADDRESS]' ,address)
//perf.mark(endpoint);
fetch(address, getHeader(payload))  
.then((res) => {
    console.log('first res')
    return res.json()
})
.then((resJson) => {
    console.log('resJson',resJson)
    if(resJson.errorCode == 0){
        return next(null, resJson.r);
    }else{
        apiErrorHandler(resJson)
        return next(resJson.errorCode, resJson);
    }
}).catch((error)=> {
        console.log('apiRequest error',error);
        console.log('apiRequest error',error.request);
        console.error(error)
        return next(error, null);
});
}
export default apiRequest
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working out at my level.I'm sorry.

Comment: Have you tried with greenlock-express? Are you using fullchain.pem? Does the problem go away if you switch to using the “Connection: Close” header?